# tcpdump on dd-wrt router

Tags: routes, packet-capture, tcpdump

I'm trying to capture packets from two devices on my network.

I have tcpdump installed on my dd-wrt router and working correctly.

However, the only packets I capture are broadcast packets when using a tcpdump statement that states only those two devices

```
./tcpdump -w /tmp/capture.pcap  dst 192.168.3.105 or src 192.168.3.105 or dst 192.168.3.136 or src 192.168.3.136
```

I'm capturing on intefface br0.  Is that correct?

Both devices are plugged in directly to the ports 1 and 2 with ip addresses 192.168.3.105 and 192.168.3.136 respectively.

Do I need to set br0 in promiscuous mode?

A little stuck.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of this a couple of years ago with my dd-wrt and looking at my old installation notes and scripts, I didn't have to put anything into promiscuous mode.  I also didn't specify an interface for tcpdump.  Here is the command I was using that was working for me:

```
/opt/sbin/tcpdump -s 1024 'host 192.168.1.111 and ((greater 137 and less 139) or (greater 900 and less 1024))' -w `date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M`-tcp.dmp -n -U -C 1
```

What happens if you use:

```
./tcpdump -w /tmp/capture.pcap 'host 192.168.3.105 or host 192.168.3.136'
```

Comment: I never did figure it out.  I was spending too much time on it so just went down to best buy and bought a hub.  Solved all my problems.